# Titleblock hero scaling full height according to browser size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap how would one go about having the page background fill the viewport, and then the other sections of the page come in to view as the scroll bars are moved down?

An example of what I would like to replicate is here http://ideaware.co/ where the main title block section has the sky background which fills the browser window regardless of how high it actually is.

As you scroll down other sub-pages come in to view, some of these sub-sections have their own background or are just set to a plain colour.

How can I do this with bootstrap please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played a little with the problem and after little google search I found a solution.

You can set the body to be absolute positioned and set width and height to 100%.

Then you can set the height property of your setcions to be inherit.

```
body {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.sect{
    height: inherit;    
}
```

See my fiddle experiment here:
http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/SmFuk/1/

Hope I could help you with that.

Comment: Thats great! One final comment, what if one section we just wanted to have as the box height of the content (i.e. a <h1> and couple of <p> elements (content defines the height, rather than an explicitly set height)?

Comment: you mean like in this fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/SmFuk/4/ Set the height of the section to auto.